# How to read the SQL query from Excel and pass into JDBC code

Tags: java, apache-poi

Can someone suggest/help on the below query.

I have the below code which retrieve the data from database, the SQL query i am  hard coding want to pass in excel and read the SQL query from excel and store the SQL query output in the result column.

```
package com.DBUtility;

import java.io.*;  
import java.sql.*;  


public class DataRetrieveMainClass {  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    PrintColumnAndData PrintCl=new PrintColumnAndData();

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.32.23.123:8080/orcl", "Test1", "******");

            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from MSG where MID='1234'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            try {

                PrintCl.printResultColumns(rs);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


** - Excel File:**

SQL QUERY                                    RESULT
______________________________________________________
select * from MSG where MID='1234'
```

[image: Excel]

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Make sure that wherever the SQL being stored within the database is coming from is a safe source, or sanitized when retrieved. It could be a problem if you run arbitrary SQL statements stored within a database. For example, in the web environment, it can enable a Stored XSS vector when you start extracting arbitrary SQL stored within a field and displaying/running it. If you are going to be storing and running SQL directly from a database record's fields then the source of that SQL had better be 110% trusted or the SQL statements need extensive checks and sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    writeExcel(getSQLObjects());
}

private static ArrayList<MyObject> getSQLObjects(){
    PrintColumnAndData PrintCl=new PrintColumnAndData();
    ArrayList<MyObject> objList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@123.32.23.123:8080/orcl", "Test1", "******")){
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from MSG where MID='1234'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                MyObject object = new MyObject();
                //set object values for each column using rs.getString() etc.
            objList.add(object);
            }
        }
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return objList;
}

private static void writeExcel(ArrayList<MyObject> objList) {
    Workbook book = null;
    try {
        try {
            book = new WorkbookFactory.create(new File("myFile"));
            Sheet sheet = book.getSheet("mySheet");
            int startRow = 1;
            for(MyObject obj : objList) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(startRow);
                row.getCell(0).setCellValue(obj.value);
                row.getCell(1).setCellValue(obj.otherValue);
                //etc.
                startRow++;
            }
            book.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("myFile")));
        }finally {
            book.close();
        }
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That should be a huge help for you (might need to be modified slightly to fit your needs, but should give you a 'map' to your solution nonetheless). Your code seems a bit clumsy at the moment and very disorganized. You should separate your SQL database call and the excel writing into separate methods (if not classes) to handle these; I personally even create a class for the connection itself. You should also consider creating a class to represent an object to pass between the two (data transfer object).

Some things that I assumed: you are using Apache POI for excel, your excel file and the sheet for it already exist (you are just populating it), and you have headers in the first row of the sheet (hence startRow = 1).

Comment: thanks for the response, getting some error in code which unable to resolve as (On writeExcel(getSQLObjects());-----> getting error as The method getSQLObjects() from the type DBTestWithExcel refers to the missing type MyObject). What is MyObject getting error as MyObject cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: MyObject refers to an object that you have created from a class that represents the information you are passing (the data transfer object that I mentioned). If the data you were focusing on was about cars for example, you would have the class car that had attributes yearMade, manufacturer, etc. So in the code for the SQL would look like myCar.manufacturer = rs.getString(1) where 1 is the column Manufacturer, and in the excel you would put row.getCell(0).setCellValue(myCar.manufacturer);